# Filtering in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have an excel spreadsheet and I have 8 columns in it.

I need to filter Columns A and C and count the totals in the remaining columns excluding Column B

What is the best visualisation to use for this?

I have completed this in Excel but I want to do this in Power BI.

In Column A I have selected "Online", in Column C I have selected "Has TV Social Sports" and then I want to count the total in next 5 columns. e.g. If the customer has selected "Movies downgrade", it will contain the number "1" and I need to count the number of "1"s in this column.

Also, I don't want this visualization to affect the other results in the visualizations in the same page.

Hope this makes sense.
Thanks
Anthony.

[image]

Comment: Is it always going to be "Online" and "HAS TV SOCIAL SPORTS" or is that just an example?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Slicers to handle the filtering requirement.  I would create separate Slicers for Channel and

I would add a Measure for the "count the totals" requirement, something like:

```
Total Count = SUM ( MyTable[Movies downgrade] ) + SUM ( MyTable[Movies Upgrade] )  + ...
```

IMO the Treemap is the best visualisation for this data - I would use that **Total Count** Measure as the Values, with your **Campaign Name** and/or other relevant columns as the Groups (you can nest multiple fields).

To have these visuals not affect other visuals on the page, I would use the **Interactions** feature (on the Format ribbon) to turn off Filtering from these new visuals.  There's a detailed explanation of Interactions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-reports-visual-interactions